Space separated words (strings) in user input in discordpy
I am working with discordpy in order to make my first simple bot that retrieves data from the open weather API and then displays it to a discord channel based on the $weather City Name and:
I am trying to figure out how to make it so that when the input is entered, a string that has 2 or more words, e.g. "New York" can be interpreted by Python even without wrapping it between " ".
This is what I've got until now. It works via $weather "City Name", but if I try without " ", it will only take the first word as input and neglect the rest of the string.
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
import json

def get_weather(city):
    url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
    parameters = {
        
        "q":city,
        "appid":"d9451e04c3b2a30d46a555f28a3c3724",
        "units": "metric",
        "lang": "ro"
        
    }
    response = requests.get(url=url, params=parameters,)
    response.raise_for_status()

    json_data = response.json()

    weather_description = json_data["weather"][0]["description"]
    main_temp = json_data["main"]["temp"]
    return weather_description, main_temp

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Ready!")

@bot.command()
async def weather(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg) #debugs
    converted_arg = "+".join(arg.split())
    print(converted_arg) #debugs
    await ctx.send(get_weather(converted_arg))

@bot.command()
async def test2(ctx, arg):
    print(ctx.send(arg))



You can put an asterisk before the "arg" argument in the weather command. It makes it so you can pass as many arguments as you want.
@bot.command()
# notice there is an asterisk before the city argument
async def weather(ctx, *city):

    # converting a tuple to a string

    cityString = "".join(city)

    print(cityString)

